# Localising xib's (iPhone) workflow

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xcode3.2

I have figured out how to loclize, but it seems yo end up with a lot of paralell xib's.

Is there a good way to manage changes in xib's that as been localized, or do I have to be very strict about not localizing before the xib's are fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create outlets for those buttons and labels that need to be localized. I then localize these in `viewDidLoad` or `awakeFromNib`. This however does not allow you to also reposition and resize the buttons depending on the language, but for now I did not have to do that.

The problem I have with localizing the XIBs themselves is that, as soon as you want to add functionality (e.g. an additional button) later, you have to meticulously apply these changes to all localizations of that XIB. For me a XIB is almost never fixed.